# Using custom macros in doc tests

Tags: unit-testing, macros, rust, documentation

I'm trying to get a custom macro to work in a doc test for the given code, but it's failing to pick up the macro. I believe I've exported it properly, but I can't get the test to pick it up. Can anyone help? Thanks!

In doc / module re-export...

````
/// The `Measurement` trait and the `implement_measurement!` macro
/// provides a common way for various measurements to be implemented.
///
/// # Example
/// ```
/// #[macro_use] // <-- Not sure this is correct / necessary...
/// use measurements::measurement::*;
/// 
/// struct Cubits {
///     forearms: f64
/// }
/// 
/// impl Measurement for Cubits {
///     fn get_base_units(&self) -> f64 {
///         self.forearms
///     }
///     
///     fn from_base_units(units: f64) -> Self {
///         Cubits { forearms: units }
///     }
/// }
///
/// // Invoke the macro to automatically implement Add, Sub, etc...
/// implement_measurement! { Cubits }
/// ```
#[macro_use]
pub mod measurement;
````

In definition...

```
pub use std::ops::{Add,Sub,Div,Mul};
pub use std::cmp::{Eq, PartialEq};
pub use std::cmp::{PartialOrd, Ordering};

pub trait Measurement {
    fn get_base_units(&self) -> f64;
    fn from_base_units(units: f64) -> Self;
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! implement_measurement {
    ($($t:ty)*) => ($(
        impl Add for $t {
            type Output = Self;

            fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
                Self::from_base_units(self.get_base_units() + rhs.get_base_units())
            }
        }

    // ... others ...
))
```

}

## Update

This question did end up being a duplicate, but I feel a better example of how it was solved would help. Here are the changes that made my doc test work with a macro. As shown here, you must

1. Add a `main` function. This does something to move your crate root.
2. Reference the `extern crate` of your own module.
3. Add a `#[macro_use]` tag to the crate reference. You can optionally choose which macros to import ([see the docs](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/macros.html#scoping-and-macro-import/export)).

Code:

````
/// The `Measurement` trait and the `implement_measurement!` macro
/// provides a common way for various measurements to be implemented.
///
/// # Example
/// ```
/// // Importing the `implement_measurement` macro from the external crate is important
/// #[macro_use]
/// extern crate measurements;
/// 
/// use measurements::measurement::*;
/// 
/// struct Cubits {
///     forearms: f64
/// }
/// 
/// impl Measurement for Cubits {
///     fn get_base_units(&self) -> f64 {
///         self.forearms
///     }
///     
///     fn from_base_units(units: f64) -> Self {
///         Cubits { forearms: units }
///     }
/// }
///
/// // Invoke the macro to automatically implement Add, Sub, etc...
/// implement_measurement! { Cubits }
///
/// // The main function here is only included to make doc tests compile.
/// // You should't need it in your own code.
/// fn main() { }
/// ```
#[macro_use]
pub mod measurement;
````

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not sure. I did see that other question but still couldn't get it to work. I think it might be a different issue?

Comment: @jocull: you noted the `extern crate` business too? `use` has nothing to do with macros.

Comment: I figured it out from the other question finally. I updated this question with my answer and marked it as a dupe. Thanks!